# Выводить определенный контент в зависимости от типа фото (вертикал. или горизонтал.)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dle

Доброе время суток уважаемые профи. Есть задача сделать так, чтобы выводился определенный контент в зависимости от типа фотографии (вертикал. или горизонтал.).
Допустим, если картинка вертикальная, то нужно чтобы в коде выводилось:

```
<div class="static-grid-item" style="width: 530px;"><div class="static-grid-cell"><img src="[xfvalue_image1_url]" style="width:100%"></div></div>
```

Но если картинка горизонтальная:

```
<img src="[xfvalue_image1_url]">
```

Буду премного благодарен, если поможете в решении данной задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $img = $('img');
    $img.load(function() {
        var height = $(this).height();
        var width = $(this).width();
        if (width < height) {
            $(this).before('<div class="static-grid-item" style="width: 530px;"><div class="static-grid-cell">');
            $(this).attr('style', 'width: 100%');
            $(this).after('</div></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

Но мне кажется, это лучше сделать с помощью php

Comment: Не могли бы вы изменить код исходя из задачи ? Заранее спасибо. П.С. В вашем решении просто добавляется width 100%. Такое решение не подойдет ибо если в шаблоне написать "<div class="static-grid-item" style="width: 530px;"><div class="static-grid-cell"><img src="[xfvalue_image1_url]" style="width:100%"></div></div>"  то в шаблоне будет раздвоение на два дива. Такое не проканает ибо width 100% развернет фото по выделенной половине для фото.